# Ordered class/struct design pattern

Tags: c++, class, design-patterns, struct

I am trying to write a generic pattern for a data struct which is created from an incoming stream ("message") of multiple parts. The message sub-parts are ordered in a standard way determined by the message "category" (to avoid use of type as not cpp type) and each sub-part relates to a cpp type. For example a message of category A might look like [int x, double y]. I would like to write a struct for each message category to read in the data. I know cpp does not have reflection which would allow it to naturally order a class/structs data members, however order/ability to iterate over a structs members with type information would be exactly what I need. What are the design pattern options which would allow to iterate over members of a struct? For example in initialisation the struct could have a `std::vector<void*>` which get initialised to all the data members but this does not carry type information and I cannot think of a way to generically say that a data member should be included or where in the vector it sits.

It would be ideal to have a design something like;

```
struct MessageA
{
    Ordered<int> x_;
    Ordered<double> y_;

    MessageA(int x, double y):
        x_(0, x), y_(1, y)
    ...
}
```

Perhaps with a inherited class `OrderedStruct` as well

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of a struct wrapping a tuple. The child class then defines the types in the message and an enum in order to have named "members". Accessing must be done through <> since the type is dependent on this meta argument

```
/* 
 *  message.cpp
 */ 

#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>


template<typename ...Ts>
struct MessageBase
{
    std::tuple<Ts...> data;

    template<size_t i>
    // auto get() -> decltype( std::get<i>(data) ) 
    auto&& get() // C++ 14
    {
        return std::get<i>(data);
    }
};

struct Message : MessageBase<int, double>
{
    enum position : std::size_t {x, y};
};

int main()
{
    Message msg;
    msg.data = std::make_tuple(1, 3.14);
    msg.get<msg.x>() = 2;
    std::cout << msg.get<msg.x>() << " " << msg.get<msg.y>() << std::endl;
}
```